# Check if element has only one child

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can it be tested using jQuery or JavaScript, if a given element has only one child element (including text nodes, but ignoring blank-spaces).

Example: for element 'div' in markup below, the test should fail because it has two child elements: p and the text node:

```
<div>
    <p>Test-1</p> - subline
</div>
```

Example: for element 'div' in markup below, the test should pass because it has only one child element: p (although spaces are ignored):

```
<div>
    <p>Test-1</p>
</div>
```

It seems like element.children() won't work because it ignores text nodes. element.contents() may work, but it doesn't ignore blank-spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use a custom filter

```js
var elements = $('div');

elements.each(function() {
  var element = $(this);
  var count = element.contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE || (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && !!$.trim(this.nodeValue))
  }).length;

  snippet.log(this.id + ': ' + count)
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">
  <p>Test-1</p>
</div>
<div id="2">
  <p>Test-1</p>1
</div>
<div id="3">
  <p>Test-1</p><span>x</span>
</div>
<div id="4">
  2
  <p>Test-1</p>3
</div>
```

Comment: Any way to refactor and make it smaller.

Comment: @Nick why would that matter? Extract it to a function if you need to use it repeatedly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It works, but something concise will be preferable. I tried refactoring it: element.contents().filter(':only-child').length. If there's no better or shorter approach than Arun's answer, then I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2):

you can try simple js as

```
element[0].childNodes.length
```

this will include the text nodes as well as the normal child nodes.

> if a given element has only one child element (including text nodes,
>   but ignoring blank-spaces).

To exclude whitespaces

```
element.contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim().length > 0; 
}).length; //to get the number of text nodes which are not white-spaces
```

or in pure js

```
element[0].childNodes.filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim().length > 0; 
}).length;
```

Comment: won't exclude the blank spaces

Comment: @ArunPJohny made the changes but you have already done it I guess

Answer (score 0):

Non jquery version.

Could be optimized, but this works. `value.nodeType === 1` to check if it's an element, and we increase the counter.

```
var count = 0;
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('parent_id_here').childNodes, 0).forEach(function (value) {
    if (value.nodeType === 1) {
        count++;
    }
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0pg9np60/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this condition:

```
$('div').html().trim() == $('div > *:first-child')[0].outerHTML.trim()
```